# Background image wont show up in CSS

Tags: html, css

I've been trying to put an image as a background in the HTML element for the past few hours, however, the background somehow won't show up after I put in the navbar, I assume it has something to do with the navbar background taking priority but honestly I have no idea.

**HTML, CSS**

```css
@charset: "utf-8";
html {
  background-image: url(../design/background.png);
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-position: center;
  background-attachment: fixed;
  background-size: cover;
}

ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-color: #333;
}

li {
  float: right;
}

li a {
  display: block;
  color: #fff;
  text-align: center;
  padding: 27px 60px;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
}

li a:hover {
  background-color: #7446ad;
}

#logo {
  float: left;
  width: 100px;
  height: 60px;
  padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
  <meta charset="UTF-8">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
  <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
  <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abel&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<body>
  <nav>
    <div>
      <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TEAMS</a></li>
        <a class="navbar-brand">
          <img src="asd2.png" id="logo">
        </a>
      </ul>
    </div>
  </nav>
</body>

</html>
```

The background image won't show up as the background for some reason, even if i change the `html` selector to `body` selector.
.

Comment: not sure how you exepct help. There plenty topics on it on SO already. There litterally plenty reasons why images wont show up. correct pathing (file structure), read errors, cache... There is no way to tell what is causing the issue with such limited informations or debugging informations

Comment: Your code indicates the CSS code to be in a separate file. You don't put `<style>` tags in such a file. It's already understood to contain that content. In fact, it's not a html one, but a css one. As such, `<style>` belongs to a different language. ;)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

It seems you moved your css into it's own file `styles.css` but forgot to get rid of the enclosing html `<style>` tags.

Remove them and in theory i'm confident the image will load.

Also change

`@charset: "utf-8";`

to

`@charset "utf-8";`

but this is not relevant to the question.

Answer (score -1):

I tried replacing the image you provided, its working. It doesnt look like css issue, but rather with image path you provided in css.

```css
html{
    background-image: url(https://placeimg.com/640/480/animals);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    background-size: cover;
}

ul{
    list-style-type: none;
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    overflow: hidden;
    background-color: #333;
}

li{
    float:right;
}

li a{
    display: block;
    color: #fff;
    text-align: center;
    padding: 27px 60px;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-family: 'Abel', sans-serif;
}

li a:hover{
    background-color: #7446ad;
}

#logo{
    float:left;
    width: 100px;
    height: 60px;
    padding: 5px 5px;
}
```

```html
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="styles.css">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Abel&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
</head>
    
<body>

<nav >
    <div>
    <ul>
        <li><a href="#">SUPPORT</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">STORE</a></li>
        <li><a href="#">TEAMS</a></li>
        <a class="navbar-brand">
            <img src="asd2.png" id="logo">
        </a>
    </ul>
    </div>
</nav>
    
<div>
    
</div>
</body>
</html>
```